# Missing Mesh. How to recover?

Tags: mesh, uv, 3d-view, uv-image-editor, visibility

Suppose to be there is a dress shirt/vest there that serves as the body but it went missing after I saved, closed, and when I reopen its not there anymore. The mesh names and elements is still there as you can see on the side panel its named "VEST" but the mesh itself is what's missing. I tried UV Map and it has. I don't know what's happeneing. Can anyone help me? Thank you so much[image]

Comment: press shift+ left arrow on your keyboard.

Comment: Press A, then ALT H, then numpad . (while in edit mode) if you don't have a numpad, view -> frame selected.
Or in object mode press ALT S, there are many possible reasons, those are the most obvious to me

Answer (score 0):

1. check if it's not hidden.
2. check if it's in the same scene.
3. check your blender file to see if it's there.

[image]

if the object is not there but the mesh data is, try this:
make a cube and change the mesh to your mesh:
[image]